# Screen blinks until booting finished and booting takes a long time

Tags: boot, 19.10

I am new to ubuntu and ubuntu forums so kindly excuse me for any mistakes i make. I tried dual booting ubuntu with win 10 and while booting ubuntu, ubuntu boot screen flashes with some code in the background. After booting the blinking stops and everything is fine

edit 1

lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
   result i got

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

edit 2-myfstab
[fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sPE2.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Generally this behavior is OK if all boots successfully, All is OK with drivers.

Comment: sometimes it boots ok otherwise its stuck on ubuntu bootimage

Comment: previously, i also tried many other distros like elementary os, kali,mint. everywhere i encountered the same problem